# Notification Clicks in Custom View

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-layout-weight, custom-notification

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQImW.png)I create a custom layout for notification in android.I use remoteview for building notification and also add setOnClickPendingIntent() in some widgets of custom layout.But when user click on it the process in running but the notification setAutoCancel(true) not working.I attach some pics of my code.If anyone face this issue and resolve so you can help me.[image]

[video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ej4524HKzR2TANoaMOHgPe4K7BHowjJb/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `startForeground`, so you are running some `Service` and this `Notification` is it's graphic representation on the screen. setting `setAutoCancel(true)` won't work for such notification, as it will live as long as `Service` is. You have to stop this service by calling `stopForeground(true)` (e.g. in `onDestroy`), then your sticked-to-service notification will disappear

Comment: but i need to use foreground service for represent the notification.I also stop the service when application terminate

Comment: so you can't dismiss this `Notification`. if you want a `Notification`, which will disappear after click - it can't be same, which is representing `Service`, so you have show another (using `notificationManager.notify(ANOTHER_ID, notification)`) or at least modify look of this `Service`-related one

Comment: i remove a notification using  notificationManager.cancel(1).notification remove and i also stop the service but the notification panel does not dismiss

Comment: i attach a video in the question

Comment: i edit my question you can see

Comment: when you are showing notification using `startForeground` then you are dismissing it with [`stopForeground(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#stopForeground(boolean)). show your code how and when you are trying to dismiss your notification. and NEVER EVER post code/text as screenshot, you are forcing other users to rewirtting lines instead of just copying, many people won't answer just because it's "too hard" to answer

Comment: i stop the forground service and notification remove.But issue is that the status bar slider does not move up.

Comment: you haven't mentioned that you need any status bar moving... you've asked a question how to dismiss `Notification`, I gave you an answer. I you have any other problem - ask new question, describe well exact issue and post related code (as text!). good luck!